# Disable caching when serving static files with Nginx

Tags: caching, nginx, ionic-framework

We have an Ionic project, and we want to host some of these files on a web server (Nginx). Since then users needn't update app version to get new changes. We'd like to disable caching so that each change is propagated to the server (like `ionic serve`). The configuration of the Host is quite simple:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /home/litingjun/IonicProjects;
index index.html index.htm;

server_name localhost;

location / {        
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;      
    add_header Cache-Control private;        
    expires 0;
}
}
```

When we access a HTML file http://localhost/bizapp/v2-phone/www/#/tab/index/balance, Once the file is changed, we still get the old text. (use backward and enter this page again)  If we press refresh button(F5), new content will be loaded. (but on telephone, there is no refresh option)

Our nginx server is not running on VirtualBox.

How can we make Nginx livereload files? Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now we choose to use Cordova Hot Code Push Plugin to fullfil our requirement.
https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-hot-code-push

Answer (score 1):

More likely that it is the browser doing the caching and not nginx.

From [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)

> Cache-Control: private
>
> Indicates that all or part of the response message is intended for a
>   single user and MUST NOT be cached by a shared cache, such as a proxy
>   server.

This does not prevent a private cache (like browser cache) from caching it.
In any case, you have to explicitly *enable* nginx caching for it to work.

From nginx [caching guide](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/)

> Two directives are needed to enable basic caching: proxy_cache_path
>   and proxy_cache. The proxy_cache_path directive sets the path and
>   configuration of the cache, and the proxy_cache directive activates
>   it.

Comment: Thanks for replying. When I use 'ionic serve', browser will refresh page automatically (not caching), I wonder how can I achieve that in nginx case?

Comment: I am not familiar with ionic serve. I thought the question was related to nginx caching.